# Why is my Feature File failing to find the Step Definition?

Tags: java, cucumber, gherkin, intellij

I have the following Feature File which is grayed out so I cannot run it from an IntelliJ Run configuration, nor from the right click context in the Feature File, though it runs fine from the `Run.java` runner:

```
Feature: A Test feature

Scenario: a test scenario
Given a test scenario
```

Running from this context gives: **Error: Could not find or load main class cucumber.api.cli.Main**

The following runner class:

```
package uk.co.mytests.steps;

import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
    features = {"src/test/resources/features"},
    glue = {"uk.co.mytests.steps"},
    plugin = {"pretty", "html:target/cucumber", "json:build/cucumber- 
    test.json", "junit:build/cucumber.xml"})
    public class Run {
  }
```

The following StepDefinition class:

```
package uk.co.mytests.steps;

import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;

public class MyStepdefs {
    @Given("a test scenario")
    public void aTestScenario() {
    System.out.println("My first Given step");
    }
}
```

The following dependencies in my `gradle.build`:

```
compile group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-core', version: '6.8.1'
testImplementation 'io.cucumber:cucumber-java:6.8.1'
testCompile group: 'io.cucumber', name: 'cucumber-junit', version: '6.8.1'
```

And the following file structure in IntelliJ:

[image: intellij file structure]

And the following IntelliJ plugins `Cucumber for Java`, `Gherkin`

I believe I may have the wrong Cucumber Main on the classpath as I think it should be **io.cucumber.core.cli.Main**, though my run configuration has this selected:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried with io.cucumber.core.cli.Main??

Comment: @MateMrše yes, I have this defined as Main class in the test runner

Answer (score 1):

Your java is defined as a folder and not package try defining it as package and calling java.uk.co...

if you see the folder color scheme , it shows that green means the folder is test source ;

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/content-roots.html#adding_content_root

if you scroll down you can see its not java but test folder needs to  be green color. I am not sure how this is done in intellij

This is my project structure :

[image]

you can see that after src project everything else is a package. Eclipse project view shows project structure test>java>step definition as test.java.stepdefinition as they are defined as package

and in my runner :

[image]

Comment: do you mean src/test/java?  I have that defined as a Test Sources Root necessarily

Comment: Could you try java.uk. and so on just add java infront and see what's happening

Comment: Sorry test.java.uk

Comment: thank you.  I've just found added to the question with some more information I think is pertinent

Comment: @Steerpike i added my project structutre that works

Comment: thanks for the detailed reply, but the java folder should definitely be green 'Test Sources Root' in IntelliJ - it is currently a package

Comment: Test resources root Is not java but test, try making test as test root and see

Comment: Source is src and test src root is test

Comment: this is not an issue related to the java package being marked as a test sources root. I know this to be correct for IntelliJ.  I can run the tests from the Run class so it is specific to IntelliJ run configuration / plugins